# How to scrape option with specific option value

Tags: python, web-scraping

Suppose I got a list like:

```
<option value="Mango/20181106/UK">06/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181104/CN">04/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Apple/20181031/CN">31/10/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181028/CN">28/10/2018</option>,
```

how could I scrape only those option which option value starts with "Orange"?

Part of my code:

```
url='myurl'
url_content = requests.get(url)
html_content = url_content.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

soup2 = soup.find('div', class_="rowDiv5")
data = soup2.find('td', class_="tdAlignR")
options = data.find_all("option" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the desired pattern using `re.compile`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = """
<option value="Mango/20181106/UK">06/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181104/CN">04/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Apple/20181031/CN">31/10/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181028/CN">28/10/2018</option>
"""
results = soup(s, 'html.parser').find_all('option', {'value':re.compile('^Orange')})
```

Output:

```
[<option value="Orange/20181104/CN">04/11/2018</option>, 
 <option value="Orange/20181028/CN">28/10/2018</option>]
```

Comment: Wonderful! Appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

It is more efficient to use css selectors with ^ operator (means attribute value starts with)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
<option value="Mango/20181106/UK">06/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181104/CN">04/11/2018</option>,
<option value="Apple/20181031/CN">31/10/2018</option>,
<option value="Orange/20181028/CN">28/10/2018</option>
"""
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('option[value^="Orange"]')]
```